# Minimum antenna separation

Tags: antenna, rfid

I am trying to design an RFID system. The transmit antennas will be placed along the length of a 12 by 3m rectangular truck container and be placed at the midpoint of the height of the container. The transmit antennas will operate at the same frequency of 928MHz.

What will the minimum separation distance be for the transmit antennas along the length of the container?

N.B.
The container is metal, RFID antennas placed inside the container.

Comment: Is the container metal?  Is the RFID inside? where?  You can go as close as you like but will still reflect off metal and leak in somewhere else by bouncing off walls and go thru cracks.. Best bet is get an Rx with signal strength and measure optimum placement by many tests.  Top side and bottom or ends If they have a plywood floors then underneath "may" be better

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 container is metal, RFID antennas placed inside. Is it not possible to simulate?

Comment: Can you measure path loss ?

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 yes I can, but it changes as it is dependent on the distance with the transmit antenna and RFID tag. The tags are not at a fixed position. So I shall simulate every position within the container

Comment: Yes and map all the dead zones inside with iterations of Tx ,ocations in at least 4 corners and side.  You are looking into a leaky Faraday Cage and there WILL be standing waves with deadspots every 1/4,3/4,5/4  path lengths  Ricean fading cancellation from reflections.  Even a 1mm movement ot 1 deg rotation can get one out of a deadspot of <-80 dB and into possible reception >-75dBm so a very slow sweeping Tx antenna might be a solution. But dont just simulate it.  Do some path loss tests. I can do this easily at 2.4GHz on WiFi on a laptop with a strip chart software on RSSI

Comment: If you have some data collection tool on RSSI for 928MHz you can TX from the inside and Rx outside and then swap and measure the standard deviation or % below Rx threshold, but if stationary, there will a lot of wave intersections that cancel and dropout  (Ricean loss)

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 could you paste a link to a tutorial on how you did it using the strip chart software on RSSI. I have never used or heard of that. I am currently using Matlab software.